# How can I record user voice in Alexa skill?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to develop an Alexa skill which can record users voice and perform some operations on it. But I have read that it is not possible. But I think it is because [voice memo](https://www.amazon.in/Nathan-Frindt-Voice-Memo/dp/B07T8PNB7Y) is an amazon skill which records users voice. So, How can we record user voice in Alexa skill and then use that voice in mp3 or wav format.

Answer (score 2):

Skills currently do not have a way to capture audio. Some try to use the [AMAZON.SearchQuery](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#phrase-types) slot to capture just the text, but this is not going to be reliable or a good experience for your users especially for longer messages.